# Как получить RAW data из RTSP потока через ffmpeg?

Tags: аудио, видео, ffmpeg, rtsp

У меня есть ссылка на **RTSP** поток, там есть две дорожки, как получить дорожку с видео?

Используя

```
ffmpeg -y -i rtsp://.. -f s16le -ac 1 -ar 48000 -acodec pcm_s16le input.raw
```

я получаю только аудио.

Как получить **RAW data** из **RTSP** потока через `ffmpeg`?